# Cordova / Ionic creates <allow-navigation> garbage in config.xml on each run

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When running an app with Ionic and live reload enabled it automatically adds a new `allow-navigation` entry to config.xml with my local IP address and port in there.

After some time this results in a lot of garbage in config.xml, especially if there are multiple developers that each may use multiple development machines to run the app. Since the file is included in Git (or other VCS) and nobody cares to remove this stuff before committing it often creates merge conflicts, which is easy to fix but is quite annoying.

Can Ionic store these settings somewhere else to avoid polluting config.xml every time somebody runs the app? Like a local (user-specific) config?

Comment: Did you eventually find a way to work around this issue ?

Comment: @Yann No, unfortunately I didn't.

Comment: Too bad. Thanks for your reply anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I see this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1841) was reported to ionic-team, and was fixed as code [enhancement](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/commit/77984e1015805301ef1f6399c2f6fd7f517f8bf4).

So now the entry is being added during run/emulate command, but also being reverted after the end of command, leaving `config.xml` unchanged.

You possibly wanna mark this resolved.